# ValueError: insecure string pickle

Tags: python, pickle

When I am trying to load something I dumped using cPickle, I get the error message:

```
ValueError: insecure string pickle
```

Both the dumping and loading work are done on the same computer, thus same OS: Ubuntu 8.04.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: If I can cPickle.dump that object, why can't I cPickle.load that object? 

Isn't it strange? Python does stupid things some times.

Comment: I got this when I stored pickled data in database in django application. Then I manually changed the string via admin interface and broke it. (I think that django dropped `\n` characters)

Comment: @SummerBreeze : How did you fix it . I am facing the same problem while editing with django-admin . Thanks in advance .

Comment: @AyushTiwari was changing values with shell (and then moved to json)

Answer (score 87):

"are much more likely than a never-observed bug in Python itself in a functionality that's used billions of times a day all over the world": it always amazes me how cross people get in these forums.

One easy way to get this problem is by forgetting to close the stream that you're using for dumping the data structure. I just did

```
>>> out = open('xxx.dmp', 'w')
>>> cPickle.dump(d, out)
>>> k = cPickle.load(open('xxx.dmp', 'r'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: insecure string pickle
```

Which is why I came here in the first place, because I couldn't see what I'd done wrong.
And then I actually thought about it, rather than just coming here, and realized that I should have done:

```
>>> out = open('xxx.dmp', 'w')
>>> cPickle.dump(d, out)
>>> out.close() # close it to make sure it's all been written
>>> k = cPickle.load(open('xxx.dmp', 'r'))
```

Easy to forget. Didn't need people being told that they are idiots.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly my problem. That's what I get for throwing something together fast!

Comment: I had the error although I call close(). It's a very silly error message saying nothing useful. In the end dos2unix over the file was the solution that helped.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Your last sentence is particularly apropos.

Comment: @Allan Ramsay: I have same issue **"ValueError: insecure string pickle"**. But my pickle file is around 179MB. It was already dumped. Without re-dumping, how can I load it ?

Comment: Luke, use the `with`!

Comment: Upvoted this in Oct '15 and just found it again in another context... perfect. Wish I could upvote again!

Answer (score 13):

I've get this error in Python 2.7 because of open mode 'rb':

```
    with open(path_to_file, 'rb') as pickle_file:
        obj = pickle.load(pickle_file)
```

So, for Python 2 'mode' should be 'r'

Also, I've wondered that Python 3 doesn't support pickle format of Python 2, and in case when you'll try to load pickle file created in Python 2 you'll get:

```
pickle.unpicklingerror: the string opcode argument must be quoted
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. Realized I had pickled with 'w' and not 'wb'.

Answer (score 9):

Check [this thread](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2007-September/465169.html).  Peter Otten says:

> A corrupted pickle. The error is
>   raised if a string in the dump does
>   not both start and end with " or '.

and shows a simple way to reproduce such "corruption".  Steve Holden, in the follow-up post, suggests another way to cause the problem would be to mismatch 'rb' and 'wb' (but in Python 2 and on Linux that particular mistake should pass unnoticed).

Comment: I have read that article. I can't agree with him. As my program is running on linux and python 2. And there should be any miss-match ' or ". As the dump is generated by python too, I think the dump method of python can handled the miss-match issue, right?

Comment: @Peter, I know of no such cases (but, check the Python tracker). Pickling can (and often does for user-coded classes) call user-coded methods such as `__reduce__` &c, so errors in such user-coded methods are much more likely than a never-observed bug in Python itself in a functionality that's used billions of times a day all over the world. (user-coded may well be from whatever third party modules you're using, of course, it's just "as opposed to Python's internal machinery"!-).

Answer (score 7):

What are you doing with data between `dump()` and `load()`? It's quite common error to store pickled data in file opened in text mode (on Windows) or in database storage in the way that doesn't work properly for binary data (VARCHAR, TEXT columns in some databases, some key-value storages). Try to compare pickled data that you pass to storage and immediately retrieved from it.

Answer (score 7):

If anyone has this error using `youtube-dl`, this issue has the fix: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/7172#issuecomment-242961695

> **richiecannizzo commented on Aug 28**
>
> `brew install libav`
> Should fix it instantly on mac or
>
> `sudo apt-get install libav`
> #on linux

Answer (score 6):

This error may also occur with python 2 (and early versions of python 3) if your pickle is large ([Python Issue #11564](http://bugs.python.org/issue11564)):

```
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import cPickle as pickle
>>> string = "X"*(2**31)
>>> pp = pickle.dumps(string)
>>> len(pp)
2147483656
>>> ss = pickle.loads(pp)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: insecure string pickle
```

This limitation was addressed with the introduction of pickle protocol 4 in python 3.4 ([PEP 3154](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3154/)).  Unfortunately, this feature has not been back-ported to python 2, and probably won't ever be.  If this is your problem and you need to use python 2 pickle, the best you can do is reduce the size of your pickle, e.g., instead of pickling a `list`, pickle the elements individually into a `list` of pickles.

Answer (score 4):

Same problem with a file that was made with python on windows, and reloaded with python on linux.
Solution : dos2unix on the file before reading in linux : works as a charm !

Comment: This sounds like the situation I am in. What do you mean ":dos2unix on the file"?

Comment: I've had the same problem, solved it by using dos2unix. If you don't have this module, you can easily write one yourself, see here:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695950/how-to-read-windows-file-in-linux-environment)

Comment: I had the same problem and fixed it by modification of the source code: replace "r" with "rb" and "w" with "wb", thus pickle files will be identical on Linux and Windows and can be loaded from both OSes.

Answer (score 3):

I got the `Python ValueError: insecure string pickle` message in a different way.

For me it happened after a `base64` encoding a binary file and passing through `urllib2` sockets.

**Initially I was wrapping up a file like this**

```
with open(path_to_binary_file) as data_file:
    contents = data_file.read() 
filename = os.path.split(path)[1]

url = 'http://0.0.0.0:8080/upload'
message = {"filename" : filename, "contents": contents}
pickled_message = cPickle.dumps(message)
base64_message = base64.b64encode(pickled_message)
the_hash = hashlib.md5(base64_message).hexdigest()

server_response = urllib2.urlopen(url, base64_message)
```

**But on the server the hash kept coming out differently for some binary files**

```
decoded_message = base64.b64decode(incoming_base64_message)
the_hash = hashlib.md5(decoded_message).hexdigest()
```

**And unpickling gave `insecure string pickle` message**

```
cPickle.loads(decoded_message)
```

BUT SUCCESS

**What worked for me was to use `urlsafe_b64encode()`**

```
base64_message = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(cPickle.dumps(message))
```

**And decode with**

```
base64_decoded_message = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(base64_message)
```

**References**

http://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3548.html#section-3

Answer (score 1):

This is what happened to me, might be a small section of population, but I want to put this out here nevertheless, for them:

Interpreter (Python3) would have given you an error saying it required the input file stream to be in bytes, and not as a string, and you may have changed the open mode argument from 'r' to 'rb', and now it is telling you the string is corrupt, and thats why you have come here.

The simplest option for such cases is to install Python2 (You can install 2.7) and then run your program with Python 2.7 environment, so it unpickles your file without issue. Basically I wasted a lot of time scanning my string seeing if it was indeed corrupt when all I had to do was change the mode of opening the file from rb to r, and then use Python2 to unpickle the file. So I'm just putting this information out there.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this earlier, found this thread, and assumed that I was immune to the file closing issue mentioned in a couple of these answers since I was using a `with` statement:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='wb') as temp_file:
    pickle.dump(foo, temp_file)

    # Push file to another machine
    _send_file(temp_file.name)
```

However, since I was pushing the temp file from *inside* the `with`, the file still wasn't closed, so the file I was pushing was truncated.  This resulted in the same `insecure string pickle` error in the script that read the file on the remote machine.

Two potential fixes to this: Keep the file open and force a flush:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='wb') as temp_file:
    pickle.dump(foo, temp_file)
    temp_file.flush()

    # Push file to another machine
    _send_file(temp_file.name)
```

Or make sure the file is closed before doing anything with it:

```
file_name = ''
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='wb', delete=False) as temp_file:
    file_name = temp_file.name
    pickle.dump(foo, temp_file)

# Push file to another machine
_send_file(file_name)
```