# insecure string pickle error when uploading and downloading to MKS Integrity

Tags: pickle, mks, mks-integrity

I am getting the exception "ValueError: insecure string pickle" when attempting to run my program after creating a sandbox from MKS.

Hopefully you are still interested in helping if you are still reading this, so here's the full story.

I created an application in Python that analyzes data. When saving specific data from my program, I pickle the file. I correctly read and write it in binary and everything is working correctly on my computer.

I then used py2exe to wrap everything into an .exe. However, in order to get the pickled files to continue to work, I have to physically copy them into the the folder that py2exe. So my pickle is inside of the .exe folder and everything is working correctly when I run the .exe.

Next, I upload everything to MKS (an ALM, here is the Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MKS_Integrity).

When I proceed to create a sandbox of my files and run the program, I get the dreaded "insecure string pickle" error. In other words, I am wondering if MKS screwed something up or added an end of line character to my pickle files. When I compare the contents of the MKS pickle file and the one I created before I uploaded the program to MKS, there are no differences.

I hope this is enough detail to describe my problem.

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding your pickled files to your Integrity sandbox as binaries and not text?

When adding the file, on the Create Archive interface, select the options button, and change data type to "Binary" from "Auto". This will maintain any non-text formatting within the file.

Comment: This thread might be of help, as well:  [Python value error: Insecure String Pickle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746825/python-valueerror-insecure-string-pickle)