# Embed list into python file

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a way to embed or integrate a list into a .py file?

I have a list of dictionaries, stored on disk as `hypotheses.npz`, that looks like this when printed (first two elements):

`[[ {'d3': 936.0, 'v': 110.89930725097656, 'c1': 4.5781828608194246, 'c0': -0.11199983705745155, 'd2': 1041.0, 'd4': 495.0, 'fn_def': array([/Desktop/example/behaviors.pyc,
       BGL_Day_Av, [1482, 1483, 1484]], dtype=object), 'd1': 493.0}]
 [ {'d3': 949.0, 'v': 109.9293212890625, 'c1': 4.7908983437736889, 'c0': -0.097829151375310855, 'd2': 1054.0, 'd4': 831.0, 'fn_def': array([/Desktop/example/behaviors.pyc,
       BGL_Day_Av, [966, 967, 968]], dtype=object), 'd1': 321.0}]]`

I want a second .py file to use this, but I want to make that file portable, so I don't want to read this .npz file from disk. What's the best way of statically writing the list to the python file, and giving it some name that can just be used in the final script?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to have the contents of the file (your list of dictionaries) available as an object to your second `.py` file, but you don't want to read it from disk?

Comment: @RocketDonkey exactly.
@root I want to use it as a list object. My question is, can that string be written to the `.py` file in a way that would make sense in the python program?

Comment: Not to sound snarky, but if you don't want to read it from anywhere and you just want it 'there', how about just copy/pasting it into the file? Otherwise, I can't think of a way you would access it without somehow reading it first (that isn't to say there isn't a way though).

Comment: @root, what do you mean "it is not a valid code"? That sentence doesn't make sense. It's not code, it's an object. And it is a valid object. But yeah, this question is confusing.

Comment: @RocketDonkey Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but this is not done by hand. A piece of code generates the final `.py` file, who also had also generated `hypotheses.npz` (on disk). So the list to be written can be different each time. Just printing to the output file doesn't seem to give a valid object.

Comment: Why don't connect the generator code with your consumer code (where you want to use the list) directly insted of dumping it into a file then? If you can't modify the productor code, I don't see other way than reading it from disk (maybe a pipe?). And is not like reading from disk *isn't portable*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could serialize the list object and embed the string:

```
import pickle

lst = [[ {'d3': 936.0, 'd2': 1041.0, 'd4': 495.0} ]]

print 'pickle_string = """'+ pickle.dumps(lst) +'"""'
```

Output:

```
pickle_string = """(lp0
(lp1
(dp2
S'd4'
p3
F495.0
sS'd2'
p4
F1041.0
sS'd3'
p5
F936.0
saa."""
```

Unpickle with:

```
lst = pickle.loads(pickle_string)
```

Comment: Thanks. This almost does it. There is only a problem and that is for some large `hypotheses` inputs, I get:

`ValueError: insecure string pickle`.

I think it might be because of the `fn_def` field of the dictionaries, because they contain arrays of strings. I think somewhere in the pickle dump a `"` or `'` mismatch happens. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Dumping the file with `pickle.dump()` and immediately calling `load()` without [closing the file stream](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13395516/1460062) could have resulted in a corrupt string.