# How to read Windows file in Linux environment?

Tags: python, unix, compilation, newline

I'm trying to execute a Python program on Linux which I first created on Windows, but the following error is shown:

```
metadata = eval(metafile.read())
File "< string >", line 1

@
@
@
@
@
@
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

```
dos2unix yourfile.py
python yourfile.py
```

If you don't have `dos2unix`, here is some python code you can use instead. Just put this in dos2unix.py, and run `python dos2unix.py yourfile.py` above:

```
import sys
filename = sys.argv[1]
text = open(filename, 'rb').read().replace('\r\n', '\n')
open(filename, 'wb').write(text)
```

This code was copied from [Python dos2unix one liner](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-February/569661.html).

Comment: i'm want to read from a file.py a file.json,
i just need to do that to my python file?

Comment: Any text file you create on windows will have "windows-style" line endings (\r\n). If you want to use it on linux you need to convert those line endings to linux-style line endings (\n).  That's what `dos2unix` does for you. So, if file.json came from windows, go ahead and convert that too.

Comment: i'm having some hard time trying to find that command, asap i will try it and let you know

Comment: I guess I didn't mention it explicitly ... you run that command on linux. Should be /usr/bin/dos2unix.

Comment: i'm afraid i dont have it, i'm on a sugar environment, is that an issue? i'm working on a XO computer.

Comment: OK, then you should probably post some code, along with what you expect it to do.