# Python - Pickle insecure string error when loading string

Tags: python, serialization

Error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):    File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Elly\client.py", line 12, in <module>
     a = pickle.loads(b)    File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1382, in loads
     return Unpickler(file).load()    File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
     dispatch[key](self)    File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 966, in load_string
     raise ValueError, "insecure string pickle"  ValueError: insecure string pickle
```

Client:

```
cl = socket.socket()
cl.connect(("127.0.0.1",8869))
act = data.listFiles(1, "")
cl.send(pickle.dumps(act))
b = cl.recv(4196*8)
a = pickle.loads(b)
act = a.getResult()
print act
```

Server:

```
rawrecv = self.client_socket.recv(4196*2)
act = pickle.loads(rawrecv)
act.work()
self.client_socket.send(pickle.dumps(act.getResult()))
```

My whole project depends on serializing via sockets, help?

Comment: You might want to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746825/python-valueerror-insecure-string-pickle) for a discussion of this same error.  The top answer suggests that not closing the stream you're dumping to can cause this problem.

Comment: @EricRenouf well, the point is I don't have no stream - it's loads and dumps which means I'm working directly with strings and not with files...

Comment: Are you sure that you have in fact received all the data when you try to pickle/unpickle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem, I sent it over sockets and the maxsize is 8k bytes so it just cut it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, Can you please explain how did you solve the issue and add a snippet?

Comment: @DeJaVo the best thing I can tell you - use a TCP client object module. Basic sockets library is very uncomfortable to use as the project gets bigger.