# ValueError: insecure string pickle, python

Tags: python, pickle

I have dumped a variable by python 2.7 as below:

```
import cPickle as pickle    
f1 = open('./data.pickle','wb')
pickle.dump(datasets,f1)
f1.close()
```

And, the way to load is as below, but with python 2.6.6:

```
f1=open('./data.pickle' ,'rb')
dataset=pickle.load(f1)
f1.close()
```

Wondering why I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: insecure string pickle
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746825/python-valueerror-insecure-string-pickle

Comment: but already I did `f1.close()`